# EditText uses color Accent for this pointer in the photo provided

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-styles

I found that `EditText` uses a default color `Accent` for the pointer , so how can i change the color of it ?

[image]

On my `EditText`, if i insert `android:theme= @style/mytheme`, it will work but when i use `style = "@style/mytheme"`, it won't work.

The problem is that when i use `android:theme= @style/mytheme` `EditText` hint disappears .

How can i change the color of it using custom style ?

Here is my code:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/cap"
        android:background="@drawable/input_shape"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/search"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/capInput"
        style="@style/MyEditText"/>
```

and the custom style :

```
    <style name="MyEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/notification_material_background_media_default_color</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: add color control item

Comment: yes i tried but it doesn't work :(

Comment: which one? colorcontrol normal?

Comment: i tried all of them :
colorCOntrolNormal , colorControlHighlight , colorControlActivated

Comment: try to remove parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText" from style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EditText (Copy-Paste) Bouble uses colorAccent of you app theme for its color, you can change colorAccent on your appTheme, or you can create a new style and set it as EditText theme

```
<style name="CustomEditText" >
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_favourite_color</item>
</style>
```

and set it to your EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Hint"
        android:theme="@style/CustomEditText"
       />
```

if you want to use other attributes of you appTheme you can just set it as parent style and just change its colorAccent

```
<style name="CustomEditText" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_favourite_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `style` attribute to `EditText`, try changing to android theme attribute like below:

```
android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
```